# Gitsync in kubernetes not deploying properly

Tags: git, github, kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running gitsync container in kubernetes and trying to sync the repository from github. I have already created secret using known_hosts and ssh. However I face following error.

> "msg"="failed to sync repo, aborting" "error"="error running command: exit status 128: "Cloning into '/tmp/git'...\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n""

Here is my deployment file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gitsync-deployment
  labels:
    app: gitsync
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gitsync
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gitsync
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: git-sync
        image: k8s.gcr.io/git-sync:v3.1.5
#        command: ["cat"]
#        args: ["/etc/git-secret/ssh"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: git-secret
          mountPath: /etc/git-secret
        env:
        - name: GIT_SYNC_REPO
          value: "git@github.com:username/test.git"
        - name: GIT_SYNC_SSH
          value: "true"
        - name: GIT_SYNC_BRANCH
          value: master
        - name: GIT_SYNC_DEST
          value: git
        - name: GIT_SYNC_DEPTH
          value: "1"
      volumes:
      - name: html
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: git-secret
        secret:
          secretName: git-creds
          defaultMode: 256
```

Comment: do you  know the difference between the private key and public key ? if so, do you put the private key in github side & do  you put the public key in k8s side (secret)? or do you do the opposite ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I know that. I have added public key at github and there's not a problem to running at my machine. the only problem is to running gitsync k8s pod.

Comment: can  u  please exec into pod and run `ls -la /etc/git-secret/ssh`

Comment: Hey, The container is crashing. However I managed to run it using the command and arguments in YAML itself. it gives **lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 11 19:19 /etc/git-secret/ssh -> ..data/ssh** @AbdennourTOUMI

Comment: as you are now  able to login to the pod, start the troubleshooting by checking the permission  of the private  key ( chmod 400 mykey) . Once this done, try  to  git clone interactively until you fix  it.

Comment: @DevOps have you  managed to resolve your issue?

Comment: @DawidKruk not at all. I'm using HTTPS authentication now.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you followed the [official documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync/blob/master/docs/ssh.md).

But it turns out that this documentation does not mention at all where to put the **public key**.

Actually, a git authentication thru SSH requires the following steps :

**1. Generate SSH key-pair :**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f mykey
```

This cmd generates 2 files:

- private key : `./mykey`
- public key : `./mykey.pub`

**2. Put the public key in your Github Account under Settings >  SSH Keys**

Copy the content of `./mykey.pub` and add it in your github account.

**3. Put the Private Key in the k8s secret**

The official documentation started from here, and it consider `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` as the private  key.

```
kubectl create secret generic git-creds \
    --from-file=ssh=./mykey \ 
  ....
```

the rest should be the same as the official documentation explained.